# how to parse component types of a member pointer non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In the example code below the class B has three template arguments. I wonder if the first two arguments can be inferred from the third one, which on my opinion contains all necessary information. Right now I am using a macro, to avoid tediously repeating the same names multiple times in various combination. I think there should be a better way.

In *main* I show what ideally I would like to write.

The goals for class B are:
1) the variable member pointer should explicitly be a non-type template argument of the class
2) It should work for different classes (e.g. A1, A2) and member variables of different types.
How can the class B be rewritten to achieve the goals above and to allow to be defined with just one template argument?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A1
{
    int m_n;
    A1() : m_n(10) {}
};

struct A2
{
    double m_x;
    A2() : m_x(2.1) {}
};

#define XXX(cls, member) cls, decltype(cls::member), &cls::member

// I would like B to have only the last template argument
template <typename C, typename T, T C::*P>
struct B
{
    B(C& cls) : m_c(cls), m_v(cls.*P) {};
    void set(T v) { m_v = v; }
    void save() { m_c.*P = m_v; }
    C& m_c;
    T m_v;
};

int main()
{
    A1 a1; std::cout << "a1.n=" << a1.m_n << std::endl;
    A2 a2; std::cout << "a2.x=" << a2.m_x << std::endl;

    // This is what I write
    typedef B<XXX(A1,m_n)> m1_n_t;
    typedef B<XXX(A2,m_x)> m2_x_t;
    // This is what I woukd like to write
    //typedef B<&A1::m_n> m1_n_t;
    //typedef B<&A2::m_x> m2_x_t;

    // this is how I use it
    m1_n_t b1(a1); b1.set(5); b1.save(); std::cout << "a1.n=" << a1.m_n << std::endl;
    m2_x_t b2(a2); b2.set(3.4); b2.save(); std::cout << "a2.x=" << a2.m_x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have something like this:

```
template <class Type>
struct member_object;

template<typename RetType, typename ClassType> 
struct member_object<RetType ClassType::*> {
    using return_type = RetType;
    using class_type = ClassType;
    using member_type = RetType ClassType::*;
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf61981c13dfac6)

Notice that in `A`, `n` is private, so it will fail to compile in `decltype(&A::n)` unless you make it public.

---

If you need the actual pointer at compile time then you will have to pass it in explicitly as another template argument like this:

```
template <class PtrType, PtrType Ptr>
struct member_object;

template<typename RetType, typename ClassType, RetType ClassType::* Ptr> 
struct member_object<RetType ClassType::*, Ptr> {
    using return_type = RetType;
    using class_type = ClassType;
    using member_type = RetType ClassType::*;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I need, except that this does not give me M, i.e. the member pointer. Anyway to get that too?

Comment: Thanks Shoe. But that is the type, not the pointer itself. Probably it is my question which is ill posed.  I.e. if A has 2 members, m and n, then inside my B object, I want be able to make specific calls to m or n. Perhaps I cannot do it with one single template argument. I am looking for some sort on 'bind'. Member_object will have a constructor of type ClassType& and be able to internally manipulate n.

Comment: @Fabio I'm not sure what you mean? You can access the member `m` and `n` as `obj.m` or `obj.n` or `obj.*ptr_to_m` or `obj.*ptr_to_n`. But that has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: @Show, I apologize for my poorly written question. I rewrote the question trying to better explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. This reduces from 3 to 2 the number of template arguments in my example, which is an improvement.  Right now I would instantiate as: member_object<decltype(&A::m_n),&A::m_n>. This seems redundant to me, as the information about the type is fully contained in the value. Is there really no way to reduce it to 1?